# Is there a "using" for methods?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have an overloaded method y in class x; I call this method `x.y(...)` as needed.
Is there a construct in C# to have `z = x.y`, such that anytime I wanted to call one of the overloads of `x.y(...)`, I could just call `z(...)`?
That would be similar to the way we have `using` for objects. Is there such a construct?

Comment: You could use a delegate.

Comment: Are we talking about a static method here?

Answer (score 3):

you could wrap it in a `Func` or `Action` with the same method signature, I suppose:

```
Action<int> action = i => x.y(i);
//...
var result = action(5);
```

But there's no built in way to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the built in way of doing it?

Comment: well, nothing built into the framework the way you can declare a `using` statement at the beginning of a class, is what I meant exactly.

Comment: Ahh, I see where you're coming from now

Comment: @MatthewWatson, that's my question actually..To assign an action to a single method is trivial..but what about overloads?

Answer (score 1):

If your class is static you can include a [`using static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

MSDN example:

```
using static System.Console; 
using static System.Math;
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        WriteLine(Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)); 
    } 
}
```

Otherwise you can use a `Func<T>` or `Action<T>` as in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well... kind of.

```
static class x
{
    static public int y()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("y");
        return 0;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Func<int> z = x.y;
        Console.WriteLine(z());

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```